# spymemcached in a java servlet - should I use a singleton?

Tags: java, servlets, memcached, spymemcached

I am going to be incorporating spymemcached into a java servlet that I have and am trying to figure out the best way to handle the MemcachedClient(s). Should I create a single static singleton which is used across the entire servlet, or each time that I require the use of a client, instantiate a new one?

Answer (score 0):

The `Singleton` pattern is almost never appropriate. Prefer either `Dependency Injection` or `Service Locator`.

If you are using a low-level Java servlet, instead of an MVC framework with inversion of control such as Spring, you will find DI adds a significant amount of implementation overhead. In this case, the service locator may be more appropriate. A service locator adds a layer of indirection between consumers and resources. For example:

```
MyResource resource = MyResourceLocator.resource();
```

How is this any better than a singleton? It's not *much* better as shown above -- we're still undesirably coupled to the `MyResourceLocator` class and its static method. We can improve this a bit:

```
MyResource resource = MyLocator.newInstance().resource();
```

Here, `MyLocator` can be an abstract class with a static factory method, `newInstance`. `resource()` can then be overridden by different implementations. The factory method indirection allows you to provide different kinds of locators depending on whether you are in production or testing, for example. `MyLocator` might even adhere to the [**Service Provider Interface** (SPI) standard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html), allowing third parties to plug in seamlessly and provide resources.

Answer (score 0):

Spymemcached uses a single IO thread, but acts like a multithreaded client. With one thread for example, you can do up to 50k ops per second. If you want to create a thread pool then you will have to do it in your user application.